# JPA Projection with variables and List In the Projection Interface

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I Have Ratings JPA Entity, I am trying to fetch the details of rating in the form of native sql query.

By using Projection of JPA concept, I am trying to fetch the results in the maner of

```
{
ratingCount
averageRating,
List<Rating> ratings
}
```

But i am getting error in the query it self saying sub query returing more then one value.

Below I am attaching query and Projection class.

I have wrote the query:

Query is:

```
select COUNT(pr.product_id) AS totalRatingCount,
        AVG(pr.rating) AS averageRating, 
        (SELECT pri.product_id FROM Product_rating pri 
        WHERE pr.product_id in (13)
        ) as ratings 
from Product_rating pr where pr.product_id=13;
```

I have created the Projection class:

```
class ProductRatingResultsI {
    long getTotalRatingCount();
    long getAverageRating();
    List<ProductRatingI> getRatings();
}


ProductRatingI{
    long getRatingId();
    double getRating();
    String getComment();
    String getReviewrName();
    Date getReviewDate();
    int getCustomerId();
}
```

But in the query it self I am facing the issue, Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: One has to assume a one to many relationship there

Comment: Yaa, But it comes under self join right.